# How to debug the previous pages via Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, http, google-chrome-devtools

My issue is very simple. When I visit the page A, say `a.html`, as soon as I visit it, there is a kind of trigger in a.js which leads to redirect to the page B (`b.html`) immediately. So I can only see the resources of page B(`b.html, b.js`, etc.) in the 'Sources' and 'Network' section in Chrome dev tools. Even I ticked the 'Preserve log' in the 'Network' section, the resources of page A still can not be viewed with the error 'Failed to show response data'. I can notice that the resources of page A were loaded, but they got refreshed and gone as soon as page B loaded. Finally I can not see those resources of page A. So how can I see the resources of page A, then I can debug it? What settings should I made on Chrome dev tools?

Comment: Try setting a `beforeunload` breakpoint in `Sources` panel: https://puu.sh/J8Ltq/d1c1b7a23d.png